# Alternative to HTTP Cookies?

Tags: cookies

They say Cookies are [bad](http://cafe.elharo.com/web/why-cookies-are-bad-for-you-3/). I personally believe there should be a "smarter" way to detect the state of a user on a web app.

Say, currently this is how it works in a distributed environment where xyz.com has many pools and servers (which i know of):

1. User logs in xyz.com
2. The login module of xyz.com drops a cookie on client's local machine.
3. Now, when the client goes to Feature1 of xyz.com, the feature1 pool checks for a local cookie, if he finds it and if it has not expired then Feature1 assumes that the client is good and lets him in.

So, feature1 blindly trusts the client due to the cookie dropped by login module.

But I feel a fundamental flaw here at stage 3. What if a hacker clones a cookie and tries to do something? (which is the first obvious thing a hacker will try to do, cookie sniffing)

So, is there any alternative to this? - how will web storage, flash stored objects do in future? or cookies will rule?

Not looking for an obvious answer, because there are none. I am interested in different viewpoints of approaching this probem.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explicitly asking for discussion and opinions. *Not looking for an obvious answer, because there are none. I am interested in different viewpoints of approaching this probem.*

Comment: I don't agree on closing the question, it's a matter that nowadays keeps evolving, viable and best solutions come and go.

Comment: Device fingerprinting could also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Fundamental principals of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer), and I mean [real REST](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/10/this-isnt-rest-this-is-rpc/) is not to store state on the server, if there is no state on the server, then there is no need for a cookie to be used as a key to look that state up.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this, that how will this work in the scenario I described above?

Comment: you don't need cookies to track state on the server, there is none, you pass the state to the server from the client on every request, read the link about REST it is very simple to understand

Comment: @makerofthings7 you pass the credentials on every request, that is part of the state, you don't understand what **stateless** means or secure authentication if you think you need cookies are required for security. End to End encryption like SSL makes things secure, not cookies.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Can you show me a sample of this approach that works with Forms based authentication?  The only way I know to send creds on every request is to use implicit Kerberos, NTLM, etc.  This won't work with OAuth, OpenID, WS-Trust, Facebook, etc...

Comment: @makerofthings7 you don't understand REST, read up on it more before you post, if I pass credentials on every request, it has nothing to do with cookies. Credentials have nothing to do with identity, all the things you list have to do with identity and nothing to do with security of REST. Cookies are **one** way to encode credentials, there are many more. What did people do before cookies? There was a time before cookies, do you think there is was no authentication, authorization or identity then?

And nothing about credentials has anything to do with **STATE**. Which is what this about.

Comment: @makerofthings7 you will learn more from reading for comprehension and not arguing a point that doesn't have any basis in fact. I am trying to explain that you are confusing multiple things that are un-related and you are more interested in arguing your flawed point based on incomplete understanding. There are many ways to encode state, cookies is one of the worst. Good luck to you for sure.

Comment: just a little bit of my thought here: A session-id is a cookie passed to the browser too, the only exception is that this is allowed by the cookie law. however since this is an unique ID you can use this for tracking purposes as well (which would be even more precise), of course this would require all your users to login

Comment: @user177800 Wondering if this would work to replace the cookies we use to track our app (chatbot) on a clients site which we have no control over. Our chatbot is rendered in an iframe and we use cookies to hold the chatid so that it can "follow" the user across the site if they happen to have a chat running but navigate to a new page on the same domain. There are other items of state we track also but this is the most relevant one.

Answer (score 17):

### There are MANY (2021 updated):

I believe the information in [this resource from google](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/#storage) and/or [this link](http://www.cio.com/article/2382838/enterprise-browsers/4-client-side-web-storage-options-that-replace-cookies.html) will help you find alternatives for saving information on the client-side.

Basically... there are currently 4 different ways to store data on client-side without using cookies:

1. [Local Storage](https://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) ([Session](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/sessionstorage/) and [Local](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/) key/value pairs, INSECURE)
2. [Web SQL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated/232398#232398) (my favorite, it's a whole SQL Database, and [it's NOT obsolete](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/sessionstorage/))
3. [IndexedDB](https://caniuse.com/indexeddb) (another Database with different structure and acceptance)
4. [Service Workers](https://caniuse.com/serviceworkers) (Persistent background processing, even while offline, can asynchronously save files and many other things)

I believe that for your specific need the Local Storage pairs are the easiest solution.

Comment: be aware that with localStorage and sessionStorage any and all Javascript scripts running on your page have access to it. Putting your security credentials (token, username, pwd, or whatever) there is therefore not the best idea. More info: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: @seBaka28 1) Storing the password in cleartext anywhere is usually avoidable. 2) By definition all JS on your page has access to the content of the Webpage including the login form.

Comment: @curiousguy 1) very much agree 2) Still a big difference, e.g. a script that is only added after you logged in (some js used for cropping profile pic or sth. else), these scripts would still have access to localStorage, but not the login form

Comment: @seBaka28 2) A login form can be on any page. It depend on whether your browser "auto-fills" all forms (without any user action), even those that are no visible, and if you save passwords. If you do, passwords can be recovered by a script on any page.

Comment: Interesting, so... One solution would be to have a separate page for the login process as big ones do?

Answer (score 1):

You need secure cookies with [cookie prefixes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05). Cookie prefixes __Secure-* and ___Host-* secure your cookies by ensuring that they are only set by and sent over secure connections preventing cookie sniffing and man-in-the-middle attacks.

For additional security you could force your users to only log in from a whitelist of specific IP addresses.

Comment: To my understanding the link [cookie prefixes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05)  named `draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05` did expire in 2016. So it is unclear to me if there is such a thing like `__Secure-*` or `___Host-*` to restrict access to cookies. Could you clarify?

Comment: I didn't add the link to that document and I haven't checked it for accuracy. That was an edit by the community bot. Cookie prefixes __Host- and __Secure- are supported by all the current browsers and don't break backward compatibility with older browsers like IE 11 and even old versions of Edge which don't support it.